# Why is sudo able to run in fakeroot?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, sudo

Take the following snippet:

```sh
fakeroot -- sudo cat /etc/shadow
```

This will print out the contents of `/etc/shadow`, but doesn't running sudo in fakeroot ruin it's whole purpose, or am I missing something?

Comment: The purpose is to simulate operations on filesystem attributes that would normally require root. It's not a security tool. I don't see how this interacts with sudo in any way (other than possibly confusing it subtly - but as you wrote it seems to work in fact).

Answer (score 0):

[FakeRoot](https://wiki.debian.org/FakeRoot)
Gives a fake root environment, usually to remove the need to become root
for a package build.

Fakeroot runs a command in an environment where it appears to
have root privileges for file manipulation.

Therefore `sudo` becomes a null operation, since it believes that the
caller already has root permission. It will therefore not require
a password.

The
[Sudoers Manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html)
has this exception to the rule:

> If sudo is run by root and the SUDO_USER environment variable is set, the sudoers policy will use this value to determine who the actual user is. This can be used by a user to log commands through sudo even when a root shell has been invoked.

If `sudo` is called with parameters, they will have their usual
effect.